# Accessing first object in NSArray/UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, object, nsarray

Which number is the first object in a NSArray? I originally thought it was 0 but I may be wrong.

Also which number is the first cell in a UITableView? I thought the first indexpath.row was 1 but I also may be wrong?

Are there any links anyone can point me to, where Apple explains this?

Thanks!

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)thetextField {

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[thetextField superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [thetableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSLog(@"%i", indexPath.row);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index 0 represents the first element in NSArray.

As for UITableView, you have both a row and section number in an index path. So the first element of the first section is when `indexPath.row = 0` and `indexPath.section = 0`.

Comment: Check the code I added above, I have a UITableView loaded with custom cells that have a UITextField in it but when I try to get the index path of the textfield like I try to above, it is always 0! Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In any array, the first object is at `index 0`. In case of a `tableView`, it is basically populated with an array, and the first object, which is `indexPath.row == 0` denotes first row.

So the answer to both = 0  !

Answer (score 1):

The first object should be 0 as objc is kind of C.

As for the first object of `UITableView`,it depends on your datasource. If your application has only a section, the datasource usually is a `NSArray`. Then the first cell corresponding to the datasource has the 0 index (we usually get the index through
 `-[NSIndexPath row]`.

If you have several sections, the the datasource usually is a `NSArray` of `NSArray`. Then the first cell corresponding to the datasource is the first object in the first `NSArray` in the datasource.

You should read the `UITableView` Programming Guide.

Comment: Check the code I added above, I have a UITableView loaded with custom cells that have a UITextField in it but when I try to get the index path of the textfield like I try to above, it is always 0! Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that you get a cell with this:

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[thetextField superview];
```

Is that assumption correct?

Comment: Yes that is what I am assuming